# Prove that $f g$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$Let $f,g : \R \to \R$. Let $f(x_0) = 0$, $f(x)$ differentiable at $x_0$ and $g$(x) continuous at $x_0$.

I need to prove that $fg$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

Any ideas or hints about how to begin?

Continuous doesn't mean differentiable... so if we don't know that $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then how are we supposed to solve it?

Comment: There is no reason that $fg$ is differentiable. take $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=|x|$, $x_0=0$.

Comment: How can $f(x) = 1$ it violates hypothesis @tetori

Comment: @DonLarynx Oh, it is my mistake.

Comment: f differentiable at x0 and g continuous at x0. How can we know if g is differentiable at x0 in order to prove that f*g is differentiable at x0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)g(x)-0}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)\frac{f(x)}{x-x_0}=g(x_0)f'(x_0)$$